# serving static files with comanche

Tags: static, smalltalk, pharo, httpserver

I used to use this code to serve static files from Comanche web server from within Pharo 1.2 image:

```
createService
| contentPath dirPath  svc ma |

    contentPath := 'htdocs'.
    dirPath := FileDirectory default fullNameFor: contentPath.
    svc := (HttpService on: self port)
        name: 'seaside-' , self port greaseString.
    ma := ModuleAssembly core.
    ma alias: '/static' to: [
        ma serverRoot: dirPath.
        ma documentRoot: dirPath.
        ma directoryIndex: 'index.html index.htm'.
        ma serveFiles ].
    ma addPlug: self.
    svc plug: ma rootModule.
    ^ svc
```

The code if from http://samadhiweb.com/blog/2011.07.10.seaside.comanche.staticfiles.html

Unfortunately, this doesn't work any more on Pharo 1.3. ModuleAssembly class doesn't exist any more. So how do I setup comanche to serve static files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have the full Komanche loaded. The prepared Seaside images use `KomHttpServerLight` which just contains the bare minimum web-server functionality Seaside requires. To get the full thing you need to load `DynamicBindings`, `KomServices`, `KomHttpServer`, and maybe other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Seaside in that image, another option is to load the Seaside-Filesystem package from the [Seaside30LGPL](http://www.squeaksource.com/Seaside30LGPL) repository. You can then setup an 'external directory' handler that servers files from the disk.

We use this only for development though, so I do not know about its performance in deployment.